# Como usar 2 bancos de dados usando Room Sqlite?

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, android-room

Olá.
É possível usar múltiplos DB usando Room do Sqlite? No meu caso preciso usar 2 DB, se  for possível como trocar do DB1 para DB2 dinâmicamente?

Comment: Quando vc chama o `databaseBuilder`, um dos parâmetros é o nome do banco. Passe um nome diferente e estará usando um banco diferente.

Comment: Ok @Leonardo Lima, consegui aqui, muito obrigado amigo. essa é uma resposta válida.